# Orientation font problem in QGIS

Tags: qgis-2.12

In some maps, the orientation font in the toolbar get messy( I work with Window 7 professional):

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to open a new project after i restart the computer- still it as not solved the problem.
I added those 2 pictures for the example, but it occurred also in all other toolbar. Even when i change the style into window (in option--> general) the problem still remain.

Answer (score 2):

This looks very weird indeed!

Do you have any language settings that hints that anything should be presented as text reading "right to left" (i.e. Arabic or ...)? Look in the Project settings...

Can't really imagine this could be the only problem though.

Is it only QGIS, or other software as well?

Comment: just the QGIS software